# MonoTouch - Failed to compile interface file

Tags: mono, touch

I have a mini mac with Lion osx, I installed Xcode 4.3.2 from the app store, after which I downloaded the mono touch trial software. When I compile a brand new project using mono develop I get the below error:

```
Failed to compile interface file. 

Building: 12 (Debug|iPhoneSimulator)

Building Solution 12

Building: 12 (Debug|iPhoneSimulator)

Performing main compilation...
/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/smcs /noconfig "/out:/Users/aegonaegon/Projects/12/12/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/12.exe" "/r:/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.dll" "/r:/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Xml.dll" "/r:/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Core.dll" "/r:/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/monotouch.dll" /nologo /warn:4 /debug:+ /debug:full /optimize- /codepage:utf8 "/define:DEBUG"  /t:exe "/Users/aegonaegon/Projects/12/12/Main.cs" "/Users/aegonaegon/Projects/12/12/AppDelegate.cs" "/Users/aegonaegon/Projects/12/12/12ViewController.cs" "/Users/aegonaegon/Projects/12/12/12ViewController.designer.cs" 

Compiling interface definitions
/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool --errors --warnings --notices --output-format human-readable-text "/Users/aegonaegon/Projects/12/12/12ViewController.xib" --compile "/Users/aegonaegon/Projects/12/12/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/12.app/12ViewController.nib" --sdk "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.1.3.sdk"
/* com.apple.ibtool.errors */
Internal Error:
    Description: Illegal invocation. Try 'man ibtool' for more information.
ibtool exited with code 1
Build complete -- 1 error, 0 warnings

---------------------- Done ----------------------

Build: 1 error, 0 warnings
```

I have un-installed xcode 4.32, mono develop and re-installed but to no success.
Any help on this issue will be helpful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You might have an old ibtool in /Developer from a previous Xcode install. What does `/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool --version` show?

You can ensure you're using the latest ibtool by doing this:

`sudo /usr/bin/xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`